# AJAX from within a Safari Extension's injected script

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, javascript-injection, getjson

I'm trying to expand a shorturl using an API in an injected script in a Safari Extension:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?format=json&url=' +  encodeURIComponent(href) + '&callback=?', function(data) {

    console.log(data);
});
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery15103411371528636664_1298845652395
```

I've tried a different API and get the same error, so I know it is not that. Also, if I execute the same code from the console, I get a successful response. So it must be something to do with being inside the Safari Extension's injected script.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems to me like $ finds the way to the named variable, but the variable value is lost... have you tried to just log the jquery object?

Comment: Ian, I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: have you tried it with a full $.ajax statement instead? Looks like it is not finding the returned jquery function. You may also want to look at doing JSONP more manually and define your return function yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to add jQuery to the plugin first. Here's an example of how:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("script");
newElement.type = "text/javascript";
newElement.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.insertBefore(newElement, document.body.firstChild);
```

Then you can do jQuery in a tab using your plugin.  ;)

Comment: this is not the case. The error message contains evidence that jQuery is already loaded; it attaches its own callback name "jQuery15103411371528636664_1298845652395" on the GET, which is returned by the server along with the data.